# Groupby inside groupby and All() performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

I am having a query which groups data twice:

```
var query = (from a in Context.SetA()
from b in Context.SetB().Where(x => x.aId == a.Id) // 1-to-many
from c in Context.SetC().Where(x => x.bId == b.Id) // 1-to-many
group new {...} by new {...} into g
select new
{
    g.Key.X,
    g.Key.Y,
    g.Sum(x => x....), // etc, lots of Sums
});

from (q in query
group q by true
select new 
{
    g.Key.Z,
    g.Sum(x => x.....), // etc, lots of Sums
});
```

This all works well, and performance is acceptable. Now when I add All (or Any, makes no difference) in both groupings

```
g.All(x => x.Flag)
```

performance drops drastically. It becomes like 10x slower, and goes from 5s to 50s. Numbers are not accurate, its just to get the idea.

I am doing grouping twice, since I have three levels of 1-to-many relationships, and I do summary on all levels (Sum of parent, sum of children and sum of grandchildren values).

Any ideas what can I do to improve performance?

Comment: Probably there is an index that is a multi-field index that doesn't cover the `Flag`. You would need to analyze the query execution plan of the different queries generated by EF to see this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there are not natural SQL `GROUP BY` aggregates which can be mapped to `All` / `Any` applied to the grouping, so the EF SQL translation is inefficient.

The solution is to use their aggregate equivalents.

So instead of

```
g.All(x => x.Flag)
```

you could use

```
g.Min(x => x.Flag ? 1 : 0) == 1
```

and respectively

```
g.Any(x => x.Flag)
```

can be replaced with

```
g.Max(x => x.Flag ? 1 : 0) == 1
```

**Update:** Strangely, EF generates 2 `MIN` / `MAX` calls for the above expressions. Which is fixed by adding at the end (after `== 1`) the counterintuitive `? true : false`

Comment: Thanks Ivan, Min improved performance significantly. If anyone does copy / paste from above code, x.Flag ? 0 : 1 should be x.Flag ? 1 : 0.

Comment: You are welcome :) Answer fixed with the correct expressions, thanks for pointing that out!